# SSRS add Horizontal gridlines on Tablix to occupy the remaining space of report body in PDF format

Tags: reporting-services, rdl, ssrs-2016

I know this question has been asked multiple times and were already answered using workarounds multiple times also. But just in case this 2021, someone might have a better solution for this.

What I have tried so far:

1. Background Image - It's hard(impossible) to align the contents perfectly.
2. Adding additional table rows and show/hide them based on row count. - Sometimes a row content could occupy more than 1 rows, thus generating an extra page.

This is my desired output.
[image: Desired Output]

But then, this inevitably happens:
[image: Page 1]

[image]

Any suggestions, workarounds, opinions are gladly accepted. If ever an official solution exists, much better. Thanks.

Comment: Is the issue that there are empty rows on the report? Could you also include a picture of the report in design mode as well and shows the groupings?

Comment: @papermoon88 Hi, thanks in advance. The issue is as what you can notice on picture 2 and 3, when there is/are row/s that occupies more that one line. Then the computational estimate to hide/show the additional empty rows are off and in return generates extra additional empty rows onto next page.

Comment: @papermoon88 I'll post the screenshot of groupings in design mode later, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add additional logic to your hidden logic to account for the extra space in the Remarks.

This will add additional rows for every 60 characters:

```
CountRows() + SUM(INT(LEN(Fields.Remarks.Value) / 60))
```

You may have to play with the 60 number - it's just a guesstimate based on the remarks in your example. It won't be perfect since two text lines don't quite make up a single row but it should be close.

Comment: Thanks. But this is actually how I currently handle it, and I want to perfectly handle this so called 'guesstimate'. Aside from this kind of solution, do you have other in mind? Thanks again.

Comment: I did not entirely understood your answer, haha, I'll give it a try. Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi, you're answer did open up a lot of possible solutions to me, very very thankful.